# SEO - will a dynamicaly created link that looks like this get indexed?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, indexing

```
chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>
```

chevrolet/ has an index.php file that pulls the data for the page..

will this link be followed and indexed properly?

I have never created a dynamic link so i am just wondering.

Is it completely wrong to leave out the index.php and just put the GET variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL will be crawled, followed and indexed in exactly the same way like with index.php in front of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it will be.. BUT dynamic urls can be treated as duplicate content. (depending on how much your page changes or if at all)

To be safe, I would add a canonical.

Duplicate Content: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/duplicate-content-in-a-post-panda-world